# .Net app.config file ignored when under c:\ProgramFiles\

Tags: c#, .net, app-config

I have a strange phenomen

I have .Net 4.0 app. 
When the myapp.exe.config is under the normal programfiles folder it is ignored. Even if I delete it or write nonsense in it the myapp.exe works and it seems to me that values are taken from a previous installation.

When I copy the folder to e.g. to Desktop it works correct.

Edit: when I copy form c:programfiles\myapp\ to c:\programfiles\copy of myapp\ it works 
It seems to be only a problem in the progamfile folder where a previous installation has benn made. (I guess)

Any ideas?

Best regards

Comment: how are you starting the application? if you browse to the .exe folder in windows explorer and double click on the executable, unless the code is really doing crazy things inside it should really use the .exe.config file available in the same location. is this Windows Forms application?

Comment: Is your application .exe file in C:\ProgramFiles folder. The app.config file that your exe uses is the one in the same folder where your exe resides.

Comment: Perhaps a stupid question, but can it be that you have an icon on your desktop from which you start your application, and that icon happens to be the .exe file, and not a shortcut?

Comment: how do you know your exe.config is ignored?

Comment: private void ApplicationStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            var str3 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FirstParameter"];

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str3))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Nichts gefunden");
                
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Gefundne");
            }

Comment: My crystal ball says that the Setting has "user" scope and that you didn't increment the [AssemblyVersion] of your main EXE project.  So yes, it reads the setting from the previous version.

Answer (score 3):

Could you share your operating system with us? I have had similar problems in the past with an application (Win 2008). One simple work arround if you are not the system administrator, is to edit the .config file on another location, and then place it back.

Sometimes the content of a file is not really editted, however a copy is created with your changed on the back, which is confusing.

Comment: +1 I recall having this happen, now that you mention it, on a Win2k8 server with UAC on.

Comment: It is indeed UAC that causes this behaviour. The real solution would be to configure UAC. For me though, that was not the option at the time.

Comment: Edit: when I copy form c:programfiles\myapp\ to c:\programfiles\copy of myapp\ it works 
It seems to be only a problem in the progamfile folder where a previous installation has benn made. (I guess)

Comment: What worked for me was to copy the configuration file to the desktop, edit it there, and then copy it back. Give this one a try as well. Its the program files folder where the UAC doesnt allow you to change the content.

Comment: Found it

There is a folder
C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files\myapp

Where there was the config which was taken.

Comment: @woax Right; UAC was forcing you to edit that per-user file instead of the program's file, and that file isn't used at all. You can do what asbb did; edit a copy of it, then move that copy back (after the UAC prompt)

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you are dealing with a case of "compatibility files" - in your Program Files folder you have a file saved in the Compatibility files view that is being read instead of your actual file.

Delete the compatibility files and everything should work correctly.

[image]

In [this](http://windowsconnected.com/blogs/jerry/archive/2005/12/19/86.aspx) article, in the "how about the ugly part?" you will find described exactly your scenario.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

There is a folder
C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files\myapp

Where there was the config which was taken.

This "feature" comes that my app runs not as admin.
Read the comments to UAC.
This happens only to Win7 and Vista. Not on XP.

regards

Comment: That's right, although the config should not be a full copy of your config file. Only the parts that you save (through the Settings framework) are stored there.